# cmake- Find uncompiled libs

Tags: cmake

I'm building a project that uses Ogre and CEGUI, and cmake has a building tool. I'm currently running into some issues: CEGUI can't find it's uncompiled dependancies, while Ogre do find them. The general structure of the project is:

```
Base
   BaseLevelCmake
   Deps
   CEGUI
     UpperLevelCmake
   Ogre
     UpperLevelCmake
   There deps
Project
   MyProjectCmakelist
```

So this question is a two aspect question:

1. How can I make Cmake find uncompiled code?
2. How can I hint locations of the deps without modify Upper level Cmake list?«

my goal is the fetch from a SCM the Base folder, start a GetDeps(.sh/.bat) that will fetch all deps, and then call cmake, that will make the build files for everything and configure Ogre and CEGUI.

Right now, I have to manually build pretty much all deps and the add there path to the environment so that they could be findable. It would be useful if everything is auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't develop/maintain CEGUI, instead tracking the uncompiling source yourself, why not  use whatever build and install scripts upstream provides? You can either use

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT CEGUIlib 
    COMMAND CEGUI build script
    COMMAND CEGUI install script
)
```

or 
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(CEGUIlib_build_install
        COMMAND CEGUI build script
        COMMAND CEGUI install script
    )

If you do develop/maintain CEGUI, and want to put all source files in an array, you can use

```
FILE(GLOB ...)
```

or

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURES ...)
```

to catch all your source files, plus you can use

```
LIST(APPEND ... )
LIST(REMOVE_ITEM ...)
```

to add/remove the source code from list.

For find library, you can use

```
FIND_LABRARY(...)
```

to do that.

Comment: I'm not maintaining CEGUI but I'm using it in a project: What I aim for is to be able to check out my project and build it on a PC, and thus I need to build the dependencies... 

I would be easier and faster to deploy the project if there you be a way to do that without human interaction (well a minimal, some human has to fetch said project and ask it to build...)